# How to stop generating multiple buy signal in PINE Editor

Tags: pine-script, trading

In Tradingview, how to stop generating multiple buy signal if already one buy signal is activated.

Answer (score 0):

set pyramiding equal to 0 or close/exit previous positions before opening a new one